# Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop - 16.04, 18.04

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, ecryptfs

My Ubuntu is stuck in a login loop when trying to enter my desktop. When I login, the screen gets black and soon after that the login screen comes back.

Answer (score 0):

After using CTRL-ALT-F1 to login to a console session, I found my home directory was replaced by a README.txt and a file that pointed to a nonexisting directory /usr/share/ecryptfs

The solution to fix this was to reinstall the ecryptfs-utils with
sudo apt-get install ecryptfs-utils
and reboot.